# How many elements does a multidimensional array has, if the elements are not separated by commas?

Tags: php

I have a "simple" question.

I am currently working on a program to search and filter through multiple multidimensional arrays. Now I printed an array and it showed me an output similar to this.

```
Array(
    [host_/_service] => Array ([0] => object)
    [host_/_service] => Array ([0] => object [1] => Server [2] => localhost )
    [host_/_service] => Array ([0] => object [1] => Server [2] => localhost )
```

and so on, and so forth. Now I have discussed this with a colleague of mine and he says that in this array, there is in fact only one element to be selected since the other arrays are not separated by commas.

Unfortunately my colleague was not able to explain to me why this is the way it is and so I though some of you fellas my know more. I have no problem whatsoever, just curios to know more about this topic and if it is actually true.

P.S

I am really a novice when it comes to programming, so my understanding is quite limited.

P.P.S

Here is the code that actually outputs this results, just after it went through the loop.

```
 $my_array = array();
        foreach ($a->getSomething() as $key => $value {
          $my_array[$value['host'].’_/_’.$value['service']][] = $value['hs'];
        }
print_r($my_array);
```

Comment: it would help to show the code and data structure which generated the output. It looks like it _might_ be the result of more than one print command (possibly on the same variable, at different stages of processing). It's a bit odd mainly because you can't normally have a single array with multiple keys of the same name, containing different data.

Comment: @ADyson I edited the question. At the end you can see the loop that outputs this result.

Comment: Actually that doesn't output anything. It just assigns values to an array. Where is the code to actually print stuff to the output?

Comment: @ADyson Just below the last line of the code. a simple print_r($my_array);. Thats all

Comment: Ok so as I said before it would help to have some data, too. Specifically, the output of `$a->getSomething()`.

Comment: Showing code that does something with data, when we don’t actually know what that data is, is rather pointless. You should provide a [mre] in such cases, that allows us to reproduce the whole situation.

Comment: I made a little demo using some sample input (using what I assume must be the input structure): http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9c068a3c05b96dd2c66c7f208a8a906f712aae97 As you can see, it's perfectly possible for the code to produce output in a similar format to what you're seeing. (it might have been better for you to show us some real output rather than a faked sample). Anyway as far as I can see your colleague is talking nonsense. The outer structure is an array of arrays. Perhaps they just don't understand how to interpret the results of a print_r command either.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you very much for your time! I am sorry, but I simply can't show you real code because of company policy, so I had to use samples. But your answer is more than enough to me. Thanks again very much for your help and your time!!

Comment: Well personally I doubt your little bit of array processing code would reveal any trade secrets, but some people seem to have these rules for some reason, even if it starts to hinder them! Anyway glad you got the idea.

Comment: @ADyson I agree with you. But what can I do? I just don't want to get fired for something I can avoid. Yea, I think I got the concept, thanks again :)

Comment: @Malgosh don't misunderstand, I'm not saying it's your fault personally...I know how it goes :-)